# Index Decreases Number of Rows Read; No performance Gain

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I created a non-clustered, non-unique index on a column (date) on a large table (16 million rows), but am getting very similar query speeds when compared to the exact same query that's being forced to not use any indexes.

Query 1 (uses index):

```
SELECT *
FROM testtable 
WHERE date BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '03/01/2017'
ORDER BY date
```

Query 2 (no index):

```
SELECT *
FROM testtable WITH(INDEX(0)) 
WHERE date BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '03/01/2017'
ORDER BY date
```

Both queries take the same amount of time to run, and return the same result.  When looking at the Execution plan for each, Query 1's number of rows read is
~ 4 million rows, where as Query 2 is reading 106 million rows.  It appears that the index is working, but I'm not gaining any performance benefits from it.

Any ideas as to why this is, or how to increase my query speed in this case would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you really need all columns? bring only a few and test it again. You can add columns to the index, it is called cover index.

Comment: what's the data type of `date`?

Comment: You're clearly not using the index exclusively since you're bringing in all columns - meaning, the NC index is not covering your query, so although your index is being used, you're still going back to the clustered index for more fields.

Comment: date data type is datetime

Comment: @joy are you familiarized with covering index technic? have you tested what I suggested?

Comment: @Horaciux No, I don't need all the columns.  I changed the query to only bring back a few columns. Query 1 takes 36 seconds, while Query 2 take 39 seconds.  I tested again with a date range of 6 months rather than 3 (assuming I'll bring back ~twice as many rows) and saw a 7 second difference.  I still need to look into a cover index.  Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Indexes with Included Columns: [Cover index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns)

This topic describes how to add included (or nonkey) columns to extend the functionality of nonclustered indexes in SQL Server by using SQL Server Management Studio or Transact-SQL. By including nonkey columns, you can create nonclustered indexes that cover more queries. This is because the nonkey columns have the following benefits:

- They can be data types not allowed as index key columns.
- They are not considered by the Database Engine when calculating the
  number of index key columns or index key size.

An index with nonkey columns can significantly improve query performance when all columns in the query are included in the index either as key or nonkey columns. Performance gains are achieved because the query optimizer can locate all the column values within the index; table or clustered index data is not accessed resulting in fewer disk I/O operations.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_your_index_name 
ON testtable  (date)  
INCLUDE (col1,col2,col3);  
GO
```

Comment: When I expanded my date range to 8 months, Query 2 returned the results quicker than Query 1, which doesn't make much sense to me.  I then limited my Select statement to just the date column,  and Query 2 is still slightly quicker.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build an index around the need of your query - this quick and free video course should bring you up to speed really quick.

> https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/10/think-like-engine-class-now-free-open-source/

Comment: This looks like a very informative and useful link! Much appreciated.